# Address in mailbox given [s170749_0] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2

Tags: php, email, laravel-8, email-validation

I have a problem with my Laravel 8 application and mailings

I have the following shipping SMTP account:

```
Username: 122797_5

Password: *******

Server: fast.smtpok.com

Port: 25, 80, 1025-5000
```

It does not have a domain / email to send, but a username.
Is it possible to make these shipments through the normal instances of the Mail?
Since it does not comply with the RFC 2822 standard, the provider still gives us that data to make the shipments.

**.env Configuration**

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=fast.smtpok.com
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=s170749_0
MAIL_PASSWORD=*****
```

Thank you very much!

I configured the data of the SMTP account for sending emails in my Laravel 8 application and it doesn't work

Comment: Check `config/mail.php` and `.env`, what does it show for `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS`?

Comment: Change your password immediately, your edits are still publicly visible.